# Sending Source Code to an External Server

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, greasemonkey

I'm interested in writing a script, preferably one easy to add on to browsers with tools such as Greasemonkey, that sends a page's HTML source code to an external server, where it will later be parsed and useful data would be sent to a database.

However, I haven't seen anything like that and I'm not sure how to approach this task. I would imagine some sort of HTTP post would be the best approach, but I'm completely new to those ideas, and I'm not even exactly where to send the data to parse it (it doesn't make sense to send an entire HTML document to a database, for instance).

So basically, my overall goal is something that works like this (note that I only need help with steps 1 and 2. I am familiar with data parsing techniques, I've just never applied them to the web):

1. User views a particular page
2. Source code is sent via greasemonkey or some other tool to a server
3. The code is parsed into meaningful data that is stored in a MySQL database.

Any tips or help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Edit: Code

```
ihtml = document.body.innerHTML;
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
method:'POST',
url:'http://www.myURL.com/getData.php',
data:"SomeData=" + escape(ihtml)
});
```

Edit: Current JS Log:

```
Namespace/GMScriptName: Server Response: 200
OK
4
Date: Sun, 19 Dec 2010 02:41:55 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.42 (Unix) mod_gzip/1.3.26.1a mod_auth_passthrough/1.8 mod_log_bytes/1.2 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 PHP-CGI/0.9
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

Array
(
)

http://www.url.com/getData.php
```

Comment: This sounds like something that would be used for behavioural targeting of advertising or similar - be aware that the page source in question may contain sensitive information (emails, bank records, etc.) Personally, I'd avoid this entirely but if you insist on doing it, make sure your code is VERY secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment on your Q, I'm not convinced this is a good idea and personally, I'd avoid any extension that did this like the plague but...

You can use the `innerHTML` property available on all html elements to get the HTML inside that node - eg the body element. You could then use an AJAX HTTP(S!) request to post the data.

You might also want to consider some form of compression as some pages can be very large and most users have better download speeds than upload speeds.

NB: `innerHTML` gets a representation of the source code that would display the page in its current state, NOT the actual source that was sent from the web server - eg if you used JS to add an element, the source for that element would be included in `innerHTML` even though it was never sent across the web.

An alternative would be to use an AJAX request to GET the current URL and send yourself the response. This would be exactly what was sent to the client but the server in question will be aware the page was served twice (and in some web applications that may cause problems - e.g. by "pressing" a delete button twice)

one final suggestion would be to simply send the current URL to yourself and do the download on your own servers - This would also mitigate *some* of the security risks as you wouldn't be able to retrieve the content for pages which aren't public

EDIT:

**NB:** *I've deleted much spurious information which was used in tracking down the problem, check the edit logs if you want full details*

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $PageContents = $_POST['PageContents']
?>
```

GreaseMonkey script:

```
 var ihtml = document.body.innerHTML;
 GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method:'POST',
  url:'http://example.com/getData.php',
  data:"PageContents=" + escape(ihtml),
  headers: {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
 });
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'll only use this script on one particular website that wouldn't contain any sensitive information, just data that I'm looking to parse easily. Could some explain the possibility of utilizing HTTP via Ajax or other tools to do this? I've looked around for examples and the best I've found are scripts that are intended to fill in forms through URL information, which I don't think would apply to an entire page's source code.

Comment: Thanks for that! Something in Greasemonkey is perfect for my needs. I understand the fields in the GM_xmlhttpRequest object, but could you give me an idea of how the MyScript.php receives the information?

Comment: I've been playing around with that code for a while and I'm having an issue. I think it's because $_POST can't look up an entry for 'SomeData' because it's never defined in the GM script. I looked for some equivalent to the name parameter in forms, but there doesn't seem to be any. Do I need some other way to identify the data coming in from the GM script or am I just doing something completely wrong?

Comment: When you `POST` data, the data should be in the same format as URL parameters eg `name1=value1&name2=value2` - PHP can then look at the `$_POST['name1']`, `$_POST['name2']` variables. If you can post the code you're using in the GM AJAX call and the PHP, we can identify the problem

Comment: The only code I have is the piece of the GM Script you provided, the MyScript.php with some added database insertions/queries just to test the script. Did I miss some step in setting the parameters?

Comment: Specifically, I want to see what you're doing in the `data:` line of the GM script to see what you're actually sending - then we can make sure the PHP script picks it up... The easiest way is if you could just add the whole `GM_xmlhttpRequest` block (with your values) to your question. NB: obfuscate the URL if it's sensitive.

Comment: Oh, sure thing. I'm trying to send the source code of the page, which I get via document.body.innerHTML. I will edit my question to post the code.

Comment: Lots more added to the end of the A.

Comment: I tried out the code and it seems like the only data the script receives is an empty array. The JS log is in my post. I believe that the max size of a post is 8MB, which this file should be well under, but I'm not sure how to check that via php. Otherwise, all the other debugging steps should be good.

Comment: FWIW this is starting to feel like there's a configuration issue or something else we're missing - This isn't really that complex a problem and it shouldn't have taken us this long to solve. To your knowledge; is there anything unusual about your server? What OS is it running? what version of PHP? is it behind a firewall? I can't see why any of the above should cause problems in default configurations but there's obviously something quirky happening. Incidentally, in the first JS log entry _Sending Data (N Bytes)_, what page size did it indicate for your test page?

Comment: OK I made changed post and request and ihtml to 'Test Data'. Now rather than being empty, I get a rather surprising "( [phpbb3_7rsoy_u] => 57 [phpbb3_7rsoy_k] => fec35458bf49dee8 [phpbb3_7rsoy_sid] => 9a872b3d0b4bf1b44a31561761cdc1e3 )". I can't imagine why phpbb is coming up, though incidentally I do have it installed in the same directory. Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be causing problems but... The URL you are POSTing to - without revealing the server, is it simply `http://BLAH/GetData.php` or are you adding additional parameters to the end of the URL?

Comment: Nope, no additional parameters. I also tried changing POST to GET in the GM script, but that didn't make any noticeable changes.

Comment: (Most likely the 3 parameters are actually cookie that have been sent back with the request but it's good to be sure)

Comment: OK... What happened when you had it as either `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET` and browsed to the URL manually? did the param show up in the response?

Comment: Ok... Let's test if standard POST data in a form is visible to your PHP script - Yet another update to the answer coming up...

Comment: Also, there shouldn't be anything unusual about the server. It says it's running Linux with kernel version 2.6.28.5-grsec-sg2, PHP version 5.2.9, and no firewall that I know of, but I'm not sure how to check. When I changed ihtml to "Test Data" the size was 20 bytes, but with the test page it was around 80,000.

Comment: When I browsed the page manually I got the same response with the three phpbb items. Checking your update now

Comment: After replacing the URL and clicking the button I get the same result - the phpbb stuff.

Comment: Ok, that is indicating that for *some* reason your PHP script is not correctly reading the posted data - The form POST is the most basic method possible with almost no chance of complications. Apologies for asking you to repeat yourself but to be explicit - does your PHP code do _anything_ other than the `print_r` statement? (I'm wondering if there's a chance something is clearing the POST data before your output it). If it's not private/sensitive would you mind exposing the full URL you're using so I can test posting data myself?

Comment: Current code is only print_r($_REQUEST) contained within php tags. The URL isn't sensitive at all, the form is: http://www.theconclave-cn.com/getData.php

Comment: Ok, when I fill out the form from my A using your URL, I get the following response from the server: `Array ( [SomeData] => Test Data ) ` which seems correct? That said, my GM test script doesn't seem to work - I'll get back to you shortly

Comment: Damn. I have to apologise but this is due to an oversight on my part - specifically, I hadn't included the form encoding. I'll update my Anwer now with the final code which is working.

Comment: Ok, final solution posted in my answer above. I've removed all references to your URL from my code. I'd suggest you also delete your comment which includes that URL - I know it sound a little paranoid but why make yourself a target? :) Again, apologies for the oversight - this is what happens when I try to code @ 3:30 am

Comment: This seems to be working. I'll do some further testing, but I think you got it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome, sorry it took so long... Anyway, welcome to SO - hopefully your next question will get a speedier and more accurate response :/